# Docker build failed on npm install, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.17.35:443

Tags: docker, nodejs

I'm having a hard problem getting my Docker container up, it shows some weird error in the console:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

COPY package.json package.json
COPY server.js server.js

RUN ping -c 4 google.com
RUN  npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.com/
RUN echo "${http_proxy}" && echo "${HTTP_PROXY}" 

RUN npm install
# COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ['npm', 'start']
```

When I run the docker build command

```
$ docker build -t myapp .
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  947.7kB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:14
 ---> 7bef16bb2cf1
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 90402606c386
Step 3/7 : COPY package.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b839b81ee876
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 64378581f715
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@slack%2fevents-api failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.18.35:443
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
npm ERR!  FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@slack%2fevents-api failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.18.35:443
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
npm ERR!   type: 'system',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-03-02T08_20_08_546Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I'm on Ubuntu 20.4 and it is just a simple node app with a server.js file. let me know if you need anything else from me to get it fixed. Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: Hello did you find solution for this? I am facing exact same issue

Comment: you have to specific the network like --network=mynet @Atul

Comment: Thank you so much @Ericgit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an error handling the secure connection to registry.npmjs.org

Also, the steps shown in the error output don't match your Dockerfile (eg : missing the output of `RUN ping -c 4 google.com`), maybe you have edited your files afterward to check if dns resolving is working, and I believe so because the `npm install` error display the server ip.

To better identify the error, you can add a new step in your Dockerfile (before `RUN npm install`) :

```
RUN curl -v https://registry.npmjs.com/
```

Then run your build command again, curl will try to connect to the url and `-v` flag will output a lot of details, including the tls handshake. It will help understand what is really happening.

Side notes :

- You can add `--no-cache` to the docker build command, it will force docker to execute every command from your Dockerfile (and not only the commands that come after a new/updated command) : `docker build --no-cache -t myapp .` A fresh build could be sometimes necessary.
- You can add `--pull` to the docker build command, it will force docker to get the latest version of your base image : `docker build --pull -t myapp .` Usefull when you know the base has been updated.